# Trouble installing SAGA 7.2.0 in Ubuntu 22.04 to use with QGIS 3.22

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, saga, linux, ubuntugis

I am trying to install SAGA 7.2.0 to use with Saga NextGen Provider in QGIS 3.22. However, the version on the Ubuntu aptitude repo is SAGA 7.3.

I've tried building from the official saga-7.2.0.tar.gz, but there's no Cmake instruction file in the folder to guide the build, and no useful info in the readme to help with the installation.

Saga NextGen Provider wouldn't install alongside SAGA 7.3.

Comment: According to this post on Github: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/51041#issuecomment-1428063359 SAGA v7.2.0 does not build on Debian 11/Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and newer. So now I guess I might need to roll back Ubuntu and QGIS version and/or change Linux distro to get these tools to work after days  trying to configure this machine to run my analysis.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this, the solution was to install the latest SAGA NextGen Provider: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing_saga_nextgen/
(lovingly uploaded by Nyall Dawson within the last 24h).

And then compile SAGA 9.1 from source: https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/wiki/Compiling%20SAGA%20on%20Linux/

Remembering to link QGIS to the root path of your SAGA installation in the processing toolbox.

This got SAGA 9.1 ported into QGIS 3.22 running on Ubuntu 20.04.